# compare strings with multiple strings

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to select from multiple string matches.

**Condition-**

select from `CardTagTables` whose column `CardTagName` doesn't have these strings- `String1`, `String2`.

```
List<string> stringArray =new List<string>{ "String1", "String2" };
var query = (from u in db.CardTables
             join v in db.CardTagTables
             on u.CardID equals v.FKCardTagID
             where u.IsApproved == "YES" &&
                   !v.CardTagName.Contains(stringArray.ToString())
```

I am trying to fetch only records except strings in `stringArray`.

There are two strings- `String1` and `String2`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
v.CardTagName.Contains(stringArray.ToString()
```

with

```
v.CardTagName.Any(element => stringArray.Contains(element))
```

Comment: It says me `List<string>.Contains(string)` has some invalid arguments.

Comment: What type is CardTagName?

Comment: Wow, I thought CardTagName would again be a list of tags. If that is only a sigle string and you want those that are not contained in your array, why didn't you do it that way: `!stringArray.Contains(v.CardTagName)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change `Contains` order, instead of this:

```
!v.CardTagName.Contains(stringArray.ToString())
```

Try:

```
!stringArray.Contains(v.CardTagName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethign like this:

```
var result = CardTagTables.Select(x => stringArray.Any(y => x.CardTagName.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

It´s untested, but I think that is the idea ;)